# Why can't I debug my nuget package with sourcelink?

Tags: visual-studio, github, nuget, .net-5, sourcelink

I've enabled source link in my csproj and used github actions to publish my nuget, but adding **PublishRepositoryUrl** property and referencing **Microsoft.SourceLink.GitHub** package.

However, when I reference the package, I cannot step into the code nor can I go to definition:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <PackageProjectUrl>https://github.com/Liero/vNext.BlazorComponents</PackageProjectUrl>
    <PublishRepositoryUrl>true</PublishRepositoryUrl>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.SourceLink.GitHub" Version="1.0.0" PrivateAssets="all" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

What am I missing? All the source codes can be found here https://github.com/Liero/vNext.BlazorComponents

EDIT:
When I run a project that references the package, it looks like symbos are loaded based on debug output:

```
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\5.0.3\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.dll'. Symbol loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Projects\liero\BlazorComponents\BlazorApp1\bin\Debug\net5.0\vNext.BlazorComponents.dll'.
```

I have also disabled just my code debugging in Visual Studio.

If somebody wanted to try, here are steps to reproduce:

1. Create new Blazor project in Visual Studio
2. Add package reference to vNext.BlazorComponents
3. modify index.razor:

   ```
    @page "/"
    @using vNext.BlazorComponents.Grid

    <SimpleGrid TRow="object" @ref="grid"></SimpleGrid>

    @code {
        SimpleGrid<object> grid;

            protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
            {
                base.OnAfterRender(firstRender);
                grid.Refresh(); // put breakpoint here and step into
            }
    }
   ```
4. Run the app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<PublishRepositoryUrl>true</PublishRepositoryUrl>
```

and

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.SourceLink.GitHub" Version="1.0.0" PrivateAssets="all" />
```

is not enough. I had to add also:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <EmbedUntrackedSources>true</EmbedUntrackedSources>
  <DebugType>embedded</DebugType>
</PropertyGroup>  

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(GITHUB_ACTIONS)' == 'true'">
  <ContinuousIntegrationBuild>true</ContinuousIntegrationBuild>
</PropertyGroup>
```

then I was able to step into the nuget sources downloaded from github

Answer (score 1):

SourceLink requires support from editor. VS2019, Rider support it, VS code not.
To enable debugging inside VS2019 disable `Just my code` inside `Tool - options - debugging - general`
[image]